# Extending File: can't add field to Root.Main

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to add a Tag field to all Files in a SilverStripe 3.3.1 site. I'm using Blog v2.4.0 and have upgraded tagfield to v1.2.1.

My `FileExtension` is configured to extend `File`:

```
class FileExtension extends DataExtension
{
    private static $many_many = ['FileTags' => 'FileTag'];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $tagField = TagField::create('FileTags', 'Tags', FileTag::get(), $this->owner->FileTags())
            ->setShouldLazyLoad(true)
            ->setCanCreate(true);

        $fields->push($tagField);
    }
}
```

The `FileTag` class is:

```
class FileTag extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = ['Title' => 'Varchar(255)'];

    private static $belongs_many_many = ['Files' => 'File'];
}
```

The [extension hook I'm attaching to is here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.3/filesystem/File.php#L441), and it provides a standard `FieldList` as described in [the extension documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/#modifying-existing-methods).

#### The problem!

The field shows up correctly, but it's outside of the `Root.Main` tab and looks like this:

[image: Its outside the tab]

I've tried:

- Using `addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $field)` - it results in `[User Error] FieldList::addFieldToTab() Tried to add a tab to object 'FieldList' - 'Root' didn't exist.`
- As above, using `Root` and `Main`

Why doesn't this work the way it is supposed to?

Comment: can you past the full code that throws the "Root didn't exist" error? It should work in theory...

Comment: Hey @wmk - it's literally caused by replacing `$fields->push($field)` with `$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $field)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `Folder` is a type of file, but `Folder` does not have a `Root.Main` tab in its CMS `FieldList`.

When adding fields to `File` we need to check that the `File` type is not `Folder`:

```
class FileExtension extends DataExtension {

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        if (!$this->owner instanceof Folder) {
            $tagField = TagField::create('FileTags', 'Tags', FileTag::get(), $this->owner->FileTags())
                ->setShouldLazyLoad(true)
                ->setCanCreate(true);

            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $tagField);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice edit ;) just followed the same train of thought. Thanks for the answer - works perfectly.